# Dividing 2 ReportItems

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I try to divide 2 ReportItems FreeNumberField_14 and FreeNumberField_13 with the following expression:

```
=(ReportItems!FreeNumberField_14.Value / ReportItems!FreeNumberField_13.Value)
```

When running the report I receive the following error:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox82.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string
>   was not in a correct format. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

What is the correct way to dividing 2 ReportItems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=Cdec(ReportItems!freefield1.Value)/Cdec(ReportItems!freefiled2.Value)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some details about your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to Convert it to Int,Decimal Or Number before you divide like this

```
=(CDec(ReportItems!FreeNumberField_14.Value) / CInt(ReportItems!FreeNumberField_13.Value))
```